# Duplicates not allowed in CopyOnWriteArraySet even though it uses an internal CopyOnWriteArrayList for all of its operations

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I want to understand why CopyOnWriteArraySet does not allow(ignore) the duplicate elements in them. I understand the fact that since it is **SET**, it is meant to avoid duplicates.

**But acccording to the oracle definition:** 
CopyOnWriteArraySet: A Set that uses an internal CopyOnWriteArrayList for all of its operations.
[Oracle java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet.html)

So practically it should allow duplicates. Is it the internal implementation of add() method that restricts the duplicate elements?

Comment: Have a look at add method it calls `addIfAbsent` as `public boolean add(E e) {
        return al.addIfAbsent(e);
    }`

Comment: That sentence means that the functionality of the set are built on top of the CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: @SMA : This answers my question. Keeping all the concepts in mind, it is the internal implementation that separates it out. 
`public CopyOnWriteArraySet() {
        al = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>();
    }`

Answer (score 2):

> So practically it should allow duplicates.

No, it should not. It's a *set*. If it allowed duplicates, it shouldn't be called a set.

> But acccording to the oracle definition: CopyOnWriteArraySet: A Set that uses an internal CopyOnWriteArrayList for all of its operations.

This is just helpful information, so that if you're already familiar with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, then you will understand the consequences, such as thread safety at the expense of slow writes.

In general, the implementation details shouldn't be your concern.
This class implements `Set`, so it should behave that way.
It's the job of the authors of this class to ensure that there will be no duplicates, despite using a data structure that's capable to contain duplicates. The authors should also avoid potential performance bottle necks implied by the underlying data structure, such as linear lookups instead of something faster as usually expected from sets.

Lastly, keep in mind that just because you *can* do something,
doesn't mean that you *should*.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up the CONTRACT and the IMPLEMENTATION of that class.

Oracle is free to change the underlying implementation at any point : the only thing that matters is the behavior of this Set implementing class.

In other words: the fact that "uses list" shows up in the javadoc is only meant to give the user some helpful context knowledge about this set implementation.